# sequelize create() generates invalid sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem at my `node.js` `api` that uses `sequelize.js`.
At a specific endpoint, I'm trying to insert a row at a table, seems that all work fine but 
after a while(1hour-24+hours,) when I'm trying to create the row, I get the error:

> Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

The reason for this, is that the generated query try to insert empty values
`insert into company_users (user_id,company_id)values()`.
I checked the data that I'm trying to insert with breakpoints and all it's fine.
If i restart the `api` all seems to work fine but after some hours the same problem appears again.I would like to mention that the problem appears only at this endpoint, also this  endpoint creates User, add User Branches, add User settings, adduser Role and finally add user at companies users.

```
router.post('/Users',jsonParser, function(req,res,next){

var newData = req.body;
if(newData.username){
    newData.username=null;
}
if(newData.password||newData.password!==""){
    newData.password = crypto.createHash('md5').update(newData.password).digest('hex');
}else{
    delete newData.password;
}
models[req.domainURL].sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    var created_userID;
        return DB.createUser(req.domainURL, newData).then(function(results){
        created_userID=results.ID;
         var userbranchIds=newData.branchIDs.map(function(branchID){
             var userbranch={
                userID:created_userID,
                branchID:branchID
            };
            return userbranch;

      });

      return DB.addUserBranches(req.domainURL,userbranchIds);
  }).then(function(results){
        var usersettings = newData.userSettings.map(function(userSetting){

            var usersetting={
                settingID : userSetting.settingID,
                settingValue: userSetting.value,
                 userID:created_userID

         };


        return usersetting;

      });
      return DB.addUserUserSettings(req.domainURL,usersettings);

  }).then(function(results){
  return DB.addUserRole(req.domainURL,newData.RoleId,created_userID);


}).then(function(results){

///here there is the problem
      return DB.addCompanyUser(req.domainURL,req.decoded.companyId,created_userID);
  });
}).then(function(results){
res.send();


}).catch(function(error){

Errors.handleError(new Errors.SequelizeErrorWrapper(error,'User'),res);
 });


});



var CompanyUsers = sequelize.define('CompanyUsers',{
    companyID:
    {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, field: 'company_id'
    },
    userID:
    {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, field: 'user_id' 
    }
},
{
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        CompanyUsers.belongsTo(models.Companies, {foreignKey: 'companyID', targetKey: 'ID'});
        CompanyUsers.belongsTo(models.Users, {foreignKey: 'userID', targetKey: 'ID'});
    }
},
timestamps:false,
tableName: 'company_users',
freezeTableName: true
});
};


addCompanyUser: function(domain,company_id,created_user_id){
    var data={
            companyID:company_id,
            userID:created_user_id
        };

    return models[domain].CompanyUsers.create(data);
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is a data input issue.  At some point as your app runs, you try to insert an empty value.

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you for your answer my friend, the input comes from a client app that validates the data, at the time that the problem exists we have checked the data before create() and all its ok. The strangeness is that sequelize.create() produces an insert query with empty values which i can't reproduse !!!